# StackOverFlowException was unhandled in CustomAuthorize AuthorizeAttribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I have a custom authorize program called CustomAuthorize that inherits AuthorizeAttribute that simply restricts access to certain controllers and resources based on various factors specific to the user.  However, I get an error on the following line:

The line:

> Protected Overrides Function AuthorizeCore(httpContext As
>   HttpContextBase) As Boolean

The error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException'
>   occurred in MyBlog.DLL

Here's my whole code:

Public Class CustomAuthorize
    Inherits AuthorizeAttribute

```
Protected Overrides Function AuthorizeCore(httpContext As HttpContextBase) As Boolean

    Dim authorized = AuthorizeCore(httpContext)

    ' if user is not authorized, restrict access
    If (authorized = False) Then

        Return False

    End If

    ' get user name
    Dim username = httpContext.User.Identity.Name

    ' get user
    Dim user = Membership.GetUser(username, True)

    ' get user's profile
    Dim db As UserProfileDbContext = New UserProfileDbContext
    Dim profile = db.UserProfiles.Where(Function(x) x.UserId = user.ProviderUserKey).Single

    ' TODO: if user doesn't have a profile, return false

    ' get route
    Dim routeData = httpContext.Request.RequestContext.RouteData

    ' get controller
    Dim controller = routeData.Values("controller").ToString

    ' get id
    Dim id = routeData.Values("id").ToString

    ' if no id is set, check to see if the user owns the requested entity (company or blog)
    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(id) = True Then

        If controller.ToLower = "blog" Or controller.ToLower = "article" Then

            If profile.IsCompanyOwner Or profile.IsBlogOwner = True Then

                ' if user is owner of a blog with no specified id, then it will default to their own blog
                Return True

            End If

        End If

    Else

        ' if controller = blog
        '       check for blog id

        If controller.ToLower = "blog" Then

            ' check to see if the user owns the company to which the blog belongs
            If profile.IsCompanyOwner Then

                ' get company from blog id
                Dim db1 As BlogDbContext = New BlogDbContext
                Dim blog = db1.Blogs.Where(Function(b) b.BlogId = id).Single()

                If blog.CompanyId = profile.CompanyId Then

                    Return True

                End If

            ElseIf profile.IsBlogOwner Then

                ' if user's blog id is the blog being requested, grant access
                If profile.BlogId = id Then

                    Return True

                End If

            End If

        End If

        ' if controller = article
        '       check for article blog id

        If controller.ToLower = "article" Then

            Dim db2 As ArticleDbContext = New ArticleDbContext
            Dim article = db2.Articles.Where(Function(a) a.ArticleId = id).Single
            Dim articleBlogId = article.BlogId

            ' check to see if the user owns the company to which the blog belongs
            If profile.IsCompanyOwner Then

                ' get company from blog id
                Dim db1 As BlogDbContext = New BlogDbContext
                Dim blog = db1.Blogs.Where(Function(b) b.BlogId = articleBlogId).Single()

                If blog.CompanyId = profile.CompanyId Then

                    Return True

                End If

            ElseIf profile.IsBlogOwner Then

                ' if user's blog id is the blog being requested, grant access
                If profile.BlogId = articleBlogId Then

                    Return True

                End If

            End If

        End If

    End If

    ' if we got this far, then the user shouldn't have access
    Return False

End Function

Protected Overrides Sub HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext As AuthorizationContext)
    Dim result = New ViewResult()
    result.ViewName = "Error"
    result.ViewBag.ErrorMessage = "oops, you are not allowed"
    filterContext.Result = result
End Sub
```

End Class

How can I fix this error?  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to call the `MyBase.AuthorizeCore`.

So you want to change this line

```
Dim authorized = AuthorizeCore(httpContext)
```

to

```
Dim authorized = MyBase.AuthorizeCore(httpContext)
```

Answer (score 1):

The first line of your function is `Dim authorized = AuthorizeCore(httpContext)`

This line will call your method again, and the first line of that new call will do the same, ad infinitum.  This causes a `StackOverflowException`.