# Why is my MVC ID returning Null (or Nothing)?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3

My URLs are as follows:

{controller}/{action}/{id}

In this example, it is:

Blog/Edit/2

In my code, I am trying to get the ID parameter (which is "2") like so:

```
' get route
Dim routeData = httpContext.Request.RequestContext.RouteData
' get id
Dim id = If(String.IsNullOrEmpty(routeData.Values("id") = False), routeData.Values("id").ToString, Nothing)
```

However, it is saying the value is empty.  The following statement returns true for some reason:

```
If String.IsNullOrEmpty(id) = True Then
```

How can I get the value of the ID so it isn't NULL (or "Nothing" in VB.NET)?

Comment: Where in your code are you doing this?

Comment: This is taking place in an Authorize Atttribute as shown here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11847262/stackoverflowexception-was-unhandled-in-customauthorize-authorizeattribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to change how I was using the IsNullorEmpty method:

```
    ' get id
    Dim id = If(String.IsNullOrEmpty(routeData.Values("id")), Nothing, routeData.Values("id").ToString)

    ' if no id is set, check to see if the user owns the requested entity (company or blog)
    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(id) Then
```

Answer (score 1):

It wasn't returning nothing.

Your original post reads `String.IsNullOrEmpty(routeData.Values("id") = False)` - your closing bracket is in the wrong place, and so the String.IsNullOrEmpty will *always* return false.  You should instead have written `String.IsNullOrEmpty(routeData.Values("id")) = False`.

(In VB, `"xyz" = false` will convert implicitly to `"False"`.)

Comment: Thanks, Dan.  I am using my own solution, but yours may be correct, too (possibly more correct).

Comment: Your new code is more succinct (there's no need for the implicit `= False`), but I wanted to highlight why your original was failing.